# Android cursor index out of bounds exception

Tags: android, gridview, indexing, cursor, bind

I need to bind gridview in Android with simplecursor adapter, here is my code:

```
 public class AndroidSqliteActivity extends Activity {
private Veritabani ogrenciler; 
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);      
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ogrenciler = new Veritabani(this);       
    final EditText adi=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
    final EditText soyadi=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);    
    Button verigonder=(Button) findViewById(R.id.verigonder);  
    Button button1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            try{

            Intent i = new Intent(AndroidSqliteActivity.this, AndroidVeriActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
            catch(RuntimeException e)
            {
                Log.e("ERROR", "ERROR IN CODE: " + e.toString());

            }

        }
        });
    verigonder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            try{                 
                KayitEkle(adi.getText().toString(),soyadi.getText().toString()); 
                Cursor cursor = KayitGetir();  
                KayitGoster(cursor);        
                }
            catch (SQLiteException e) {  

                             Log.d("eHata", e.getLocalizedMessage());  
                         }  
            finally{            
                ogrenciler.close();    
                }             
            }        
        });    
    } 
private void KayitEkle(String isim, String soyad){     
    SQLiteDatabase db = ogrenciler.getWritableDatabase(); 
    ContentValues veriler = new ContentValues();    
    veriler.put("isim", isim);     
    veriler.put("soyad",soyad); 
    db.insertOrThrow("ogrenciisim", null, veriler);    
    } 

private Cursor KayitGetir(){  
    SQLiteDatabase db = ogrenciler.getReadableDatabase();  
    Cursor cursor = db.query("ogrenciisim", new String[] {"id", "isim", "soyad"}, null, null, null, null, null);  
    startManagingCursor(cursor);      
    return cursor;    
    } 
private void KayitGoster(Cursor cursor){ 

    try{
    final GridView grid=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); 

    String[] columns = new String[] { "id", "isim", "soyad" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textView122, R.id.textView222, R.id.textView322 }; 
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.gridview, cursor, columns, to);  
    grid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("eHata", e.getLocalizedMessage());  
    }
    }
```

}

And here is my database class:

```
public class Veritabani extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String VERITABANI = "Ogrenciler";
private static final int SURUM = 1;

public Veritabani(Context con)
{
super (con,VERITABANI,null,SURUM);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
db.execSQL("create table ogrenciisim(id integer primary key, isim text, soyad text);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("drop table if exist ogrenciisim");
onCreate(db);

}
}
```

But it gives an error "index -1 requested with size of 18(16-20)" What am I doing wrong??

PS:I changed it as Barak mentioned, but now it gives th error : "Column id doesnt exist"
Thanks indeed

Comment: Did my answer update fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting things up correctly.

This:

```
String[] columns = new String[] {
        cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))), 
        cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("isim"))), 
        cursor.getString((cursor.getColumnIndex("soyad"))) };
```

Should be this:

```
String[] columns = new String[] { "id", "isim", "soyad" };
```

Your implementation was trying to read the value from the cursor.  The adapter will read the cursor, you merely need to tell it what columns to put in what resources.

**EDIT**

Ok, this is a guess, but looking at your code, a solid one I think.

You changed your database structure based on my recommendations (fixing the space issue), but that hasn't actually been carried through to the database itself because you haven't changed the database version, so the onUpgrade method has not fired and re-created the db.

Change this:

```
private static final int SURUM = 1;
```

To this:

```
private static final int SURUM = 2;
```

Run the app and your database will be re-created with the new (proper) structure. That should take care of the problem with it not being able to find the column.

The other error you mention "But it gives an error index -1 requested with size of 18(16-20)" usually means you are trying to access the cursor without first doing a `cursor.moveToFirst`... but I don't see from the code you posted where that might be happening.  You might try putting it as the first thing in your try statement for the gridview (or even do it after you use `startManagingCursor` before you return it when it is created)

Comment: Hi Barak, thanks for your reply, I changed things as you mentioned but it gives me the error: "Column id doesn't exist"...

Comment: Hmm, according to the code you posted (from the query to the db that generates the cursor), they should all exist.  Which one specifically is it complaining about?